# Razor View IsAuthenticated not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created a simple MVC application that is using the .Net Membership Provider that is supplied with the new project.

I am trying to get the tabs to show correctly. I might not understand this right but here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="title">
                <h1>Suburban Customer Portal</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="logindisplay">
                @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
            </div>
            <div id="menucontainer">
              <ul id="menu">

                @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                  <li>@Html.ActionLink("ChangePassword", "ChangePassword", "Account")</li>
                }else { 
                  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Logon", "Logon", "Account")</li>
                  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account")</li>
                }

                  <li>@Html.ActionLink("ContactUs", "ContactUs", "Home")</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

At this line:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
```

I am trying to show the right tabs pending on if they are already authenticated. This is always coming out as true...

How should I be doing this? I apparently am not doing it the right way...

Thanks again!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you should use

`@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)`

Comment: Interesting... `Request.IsAuthenticated` should be always equal to `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`. See here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1416811.aspx

Comment: @LenielMacaferi - it a question if you trust aghausman12 more then me ;-)

Comment: All I know is it worked with the one you gave me and not the one I used :-D

Comment: @JakubKonecki I trust you too! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, your question is not very clear, but [Request.IsAuthenticated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.isauthenticated%28loband%29.aspx) in this line:

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
```

checks if the request has data about an authenticated user. If true, you link will be shown.

In your specific case the `Change Password` link will only be shown if the user is logged in.

It looks correct.

For the tabs to be hidden, that is, for `Request.IsAuthenticated = false` you must first `logout` so that the cookies that store login information are cleared from the user browser.